# How to submit the form via post and open the target page in an iframe

Tags: asp.net, forms, iframe

I have a form which redirects to  a new page index.aspx after posting .However instead of opening the new page in a new window,I would like to open it as an iframe so that it remains in the current window

How do I go about that. The current code is :

```
     <form id="Form2" action="index.aspx" method="post" name="Form2" >
.....

<input type="image" style="border-width: 0px;" src="images/form_ordernow_btn.jpg"
                tabindex="129" id="Form1_ImageButton1" name="Form1$ImageButton1"  >
```

I am using asp.net by the way

Comment: Oh ,I should have been more clear .I want the target page that i.e index.aspx to open in the iframe on postback

Comment: could you elaborate more, why you need it this way? Maybe there is another perspective?

Comment: Well the requirement is that the form contains billing information and on clicking the submit button ,it should ideal open this index page in a lightbox and the index page should be populated with information from this form .However U an really struggling to post data to a lightbox ,so was trying this approach which is not not elegant at all .

Answer (score 1):

Put the form into the iframe already. So the postback will open in the same iframe...

@Edit: if the form **must** be on the same page but **cannot** be in the iframe at the time of posting, the following solution may work:

- postback to the same(!) page
- insert the iframe into the page on the server
- give the iframe an url according to the postdata
  i.e. change POST -> GET data
- construct the target page (index.aspx) that way to handle the GET parameters